# Wordpress Child not overridding parent

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the twentytwelve template.
1. Went to my file manager (wp-content > themes) and created a new folder called twentytwelve-child
2. created a new file called style.css (put in the header and import css)
@import url("../twentytwelve/style.css");
3. activated it - went to Themes, activated the child, gave it a name "test".

I made changes in the File Manager:

body{background-color:#FFCC00; font-size:100px;}
.site-title{font-size:300px;}

Nothing happened.

Went back to wp-admin section, opened up child theme test and made test changes. That worked!!! But the changes in the File Manager were not read. That was bothersome.

Now I need to change the header. I created a file header.php in the child directory but it's not read either. If I go to the parent and make a change ("hey folks") it works.

I've spent over an hour trying to find out what is missing.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is somewhat unclear.

I removed my child theme. Created a new one. That still didn't work.

Troubleshooting tips - don't forget the obvious -- go to view source on your wordpress site and see if wordpress is calling your template. In my case it wasn't it was stuck on one my test themes. I deleted all my tests themes and did it again.

Now it works. What went wrong? Don't know? But now it does.

Answer (score 0):

In your child theme the @import url was wrong or the theme parent name wasn't the **exact same**... its case sensitive. It can be tricky to get it just. Also the child theme may not be in the file structure that you assumed it was in.

Comment: I don't know if that was the issue. I'm pretty certain the @import was correct - but we all know that we can look at a line of code 100 times and sometimes still miss the obvious. In any case, as mentioned in my answer, I deleted everything. Did it again and it works. Very frustrating.